# Is it possible to make a VB program interact with a command prompt?

Tags: vb.net, process, automation, batch-processing, javac

I am learning Java, and I find it annoying that you have to use command prompt to compile and run your programs... So I was thinking: is there  a way to make a programs, in Visual Basic, that would open up command prompt and type the code?

Comment: Yes I guess otherwise there would be very less usage.I think you should edit your question be more specific.

Comment: Or.. you could use a Java IDE (Integrated Development Environment). VB development is done in the Visual Studio IDE which handles all the 'compile and run' stuff without needing to use the command line.

Comment: I see your first edit adds that you're using Java, yet your question title still refers to VB, and your tags refer to VBA *and* VB.Net. I suggest that you reframe your question to be something like "How can I automatically compile and run a Java Program?"

Comment: Notepad and Notepad++ oh those days. ***Of only there was an IDE out there***...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)** class.

```
Using p As New Process

    p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "CMD.exe")
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/C ""{0}"" ", "Dir /B /S /A-D ""*""")
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory

    p.Start()
    p.WaitForExit()

End Using
```

But there is no need to call the CMD, just call the Java compiler directlly, in the same way as the example above. Or also you can consider to develop your program directlly in **Java**, and use the Java compiler's interface related.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to run the batch of commands you need to run in command prompt.

```
Dim commands As Object() = New Object() {"echo Command One", "echo Command Two", "..."}
Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe"))
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
startInfo.Arguments = "/c """
For Each obj As Object In commands
    startInfo.Arguments += obj.ToString + " & "
Next
startInfo.Arguments = startInfo.Arguments.Substring(0, startInfo.Arguments.LastIndexOf(" & "))
startInfo.Arguments += """"
Process.Start(startInfo)
```

---

Or just use this code to run the commands more concisely in the command prompt.

```
Shell("cmd /c ""echo Command One & Command Two & ...""")
```

Answer (score -1):

In short, yes. You can just shell a command prompt.

```
Sub Foo()

    Dim cmd_Command As String = "DIR %USERPROFILE%/Desktop/*.* > %USERPROFILE%/Files.log"

    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C " & cmd_Command)

End Sub
```

Comment: I used that  code and cmd opens up and closes really fast

Comment: This code difuses bad practices. 1. When creating an instance of a COM object, you should release it after the work is done with **FinalReleaseComObject** method and also set it to **Nothing** (**nul** in C#). 2. There is no  need to consider COM interop as a solution, because the .Net Framework Class Library exposes managed code to do the same.

Comment: I'm aware of the dealings with COM in .net; The question just asked "if there was a way...." Generic question = generic answer, this wasn't being pushed as finished code.